# Alias declaration error in C++ compilation

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I am trying to compile a C++ code on my Mac OS (Ventura 13.3). When I try to compile the C++ code using the make command, it throws an error that is typically sent as a warning. Some solutions I found were to re-compile the code with flags: `make CPP=g++-14 CXX=g++-14 myfile` and some others were saying that these warnings are typically sent as errors if your C++ compiler is outdated. I checked the version of my C++ compiler using `g++ --version` and `Clang 14.0.3`. I have pasted the screenshot of the error below. I am not using an outdated version of C++ compiler. So, why is this still throwing an error instead of passing it as a warning? Do, I need to specifically use `g++-11` for this compilation to work? If so, how do I install and use that? I would appreciate any suggestions or ideas.

**Note: I would have given the code here but the size is too big and complex and it calls for various dependencies. So, it would be useless to anyone who doesn't have that entire code network (+ dependencies) installed. If necessary I can provide the MakeFile.**

```
/opt/local/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:101:67: error: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      template <> struct promote_args_2<int, int> {  using type = double; };
                                                                  ^
/opt/local/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:102:69: error: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      template <> struct promote_args_2<int, float> {  using type = double; };
                                                                    ^
/opt/local/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:103:69: error: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      template <> struct promote_args_2<float, int> {  using type = double; };
                                                                    ^
/opt/local/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:104:70: error: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      template <> struct promote_args_2<int, double> {  using type = double; };
                                                                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:105:70: error: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      template <> struct promote_args_2<double, int> {  using type = double; };
                                                                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:106:75: error: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      template <> struct promote_args_2<int, long double> {  using type = long double; };
                                                                          ^
/opt/local/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:107:75: error: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      template <> struct promote_args_2<long double, int> {  using type = long double; };
                                                                          ^
/opt/local/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:108:72: error: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
      template <> struct promote_args_2<float, double> {  using type = double; };
                                                                       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
4 warnings and 20 errors generated.
```

MakeFile:

```
ifndef NUCNET_TARGET
NUCNET_TARGET = ../..
endif

NNT_DIR = $(NUCNET_TARGET)/nnt
USER_DIR = $(NUCNET_TARGET)/user
BUILD_DIR = $(NUCNET_TARGET)/build

export NNT_NO_OPENMP=1
GC = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11

include $(BUILD_DIR)/Makefile

include $(BUILD_DIR)/Makefile.sparse

include $(USER_DIR)/Makefile.inc

VPATH = $(BUILD_DIR):$(NNT_DIR):$(USER_DIR)

ifdef NNT_HYDRO_CODE
  ifeq ($(NNT_HYDRO_CODE), exponential_expansion)
    CFLAGS += -DHYDRO_EXP_EXPANSION
  else ifeq ($(NNT_HYDRO_CODE), traj)
    CFLAGS += -DHYDRO_TRAJ
  else ifeq ($(NNT_HYDRO_CODE), wind)
    CFLAGS += -DHYDRO_WIND
  else ifeq ($(NNT_HYDRO_CODE), shock)
    CFLAGS += -DHYDRO_SHOCK
  endif
else
    CFLAGS += -DHYDRO_EXP_EXPANSION
endif

NETWORK_OBJS = $(WN_OBJ)        \
               $(NNT_OBJ)   \
               $(HYDRO_OBJ) \
               $(SOLVE_OBJ) \
               $(USER_OBJ)

ifdef NNT_USE_SPARSKIT2
  CFLAGS += -DSPARSKIT2
  NETWORK_OBJS += $(SP_OBJ) $(ILU_OBJ)
  NET_DEP = sparse
  FLIBS= -L$(SPARSKITDIR) -lskit -lstdc++
  MC = $(FF)
  ifeq ($(GC), clang++)
    CC+= -stdlib=libstdc++
    
  endif
else
  MC = $(CC)
endif

NET_DEP += $(NETWORK_OBJS)

NETWORK_EXEC = run_constant_entropy \
               run_entropy      \
               run_energy_generation    \
               run_multiple_zone_omp    \
               run_single_zone

$(NETWORK_EXEC): $(NET_DEP)
    $(CC) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$@.o $@.cpp
    $(MC) $(NETWORK_OBJS) $(OBJDIR)/$@.o -o $(BINDIR)/$@ $(CLIBS) $(FLIBS)

.PHONY all_network : $(NETWORK_EXEC)

.PHONY: clean_network cleanall_network

clean_network: 
    rm -f $(NETWORK_OBJS)

cleanall_network: clean_network
    rm -f $(BINDIR)/$(NETWORK_EXEC) $(BINDIR)/$(NETWORK_EXEC).exe

NETWORK_DEF = yes
```

Comment: You need to add the `-std=c++11` flag to your compile options

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. An example to trigger the same error can be a single line `using foo = int;`

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You aren't using an outdated compiler, but you are using the Apple version of clang which defaults to c++98.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I added `CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11` line to my MakeFile and recompiled it but it didn't get rid of those errors.

Comment: Whatever you did was not correct since the errors still say you do not have it enabled.  Post your makfile.

Comment: I have just posted it. Please let me know if you have troubles viewing it.

Comment: Doesn't look like `$(CC) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$@.o $@.cpp` is making use of `CXXFLAGS`. My make-fu is weak, but I think `CXXFLAGS` only gets automatically added if you're using the default rules.

Comment: I see. I added the `CXXFLAGS` to that line but that did not have any change anything. Your suggestion was really good though!

Comment: Run `make -n` and see what the makefile is really generating. The error messages should be very different if it was, for example, using the C compiler, but knowing exactly what the compiler command line really looks like should be really helpful in diagnosing.

Comment: Executing the dry run did show me what commands are executed. It was using `clang++` along with other options (`-Werror`,`Wall`,`g` etc.). However, I could not see the `-std=c++11` option. This concerns me.

Comment: Add the compiler command line generated to the question. Maybe someone can recognize the pattern. What does `$(CC) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$@.o $@.cpp` look like now? What happens if you try brute force: `$(CC) -c -std=c++11 -o $(OBJDIR)/$@.o $@.cpp`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. I tried to brute force it but it gives me the same errors.